# Inserting html in javascript alert/confirm

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code for validation and if any error occurs confirm or alert dialog box appears. now i want to keep a check box in the alert dialog and if the checkbox is checked than should return the value on check box. I tried using jquery-modal dialog box but it didnt helped me out. So can any one tell me how can i do this

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Why didn't the jQuery dialog work? A checkbox should be no problem on that

Comment: @MrCode You can check here for you question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058265/loading-page-only-after-event-raised-from-jquery-modal-dialog-buttons

Comment: @Robz look on my answer please...

Answer (score 0):

Jquery modal does the job for you.

Below is the code which sets the value of the checkbox on close.

http://jsfiddle.net/RSk4v/

```
 $(function () {
 $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
     resizable: true,
     height: 150,
     modal: true,
     close: function () {
         $(this).find(':checked').each(function () {
             var name = $(this).attr('name');
             $('input[name="' + name + '"]').val('checked '+name);
         });
     },
     buttons: {
         "Ok": function () {
             $(this).dialog("close");
         },
         Cancel: function () {
             $(this).dialog("close");
         }
     }
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this exercise if I understand your problem.

For the control on the checkbox you have to use this script:

```
  if(document.getElementById("check1").checked=true)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/zQLr4/6/)